# Mysql.connector Python, no result when connection is already used

Tags: python-3.x, mysql-python, mysql-connector

I have a simple code which sends a message by http to another webapp and check that the message is well inserted in the database (2 times)

So it is not this code which insert in the database (it is done in another app)

```
    SELECT_TABLE1_BY_ID_AND_DATE = "SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE table1.id = %s AND timedata = FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)"
    SELECT_TABLE2_BY_ID_AND_DATE = "SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE table2.id = %s AND timedata = FROM_UNIXTIME(%s)"
    try:
        conn = mysql.connector.connect(user=db['user'], password=db['password'], host=db['host'], port=db['port'], database="TEST", raise_on_warnings=True)
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        self.send1Message(msg1) # Send to HTTP Webapp
        cursor.execute(SELECT_TABLE1_BY_ID_AND_DATE, (idD, timing))
        print(cursor.fetchall()) #1
        self.send2Message(msg2) Send to HTTP Webapp
        cursor.execute(SELECT_TABLE2_BY_ID_AND_DATE, (idD, timing))
        print(cursor.fetchall()) #2 
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        print("Something went wrong: {}".format(err))
```

- If I use the same SQL connection between the 2 sendTable, only the first fetchAll returns data. **(#1 prints data and #2 prints empty list)**.
- I tried also to close the connection after #1 and start another connection. It works for both **(#1 prints data and #2 too)**.

(I have to precise that my queries are correct and that the data is well insert in the database on time by the webapp).

Is it a normal behaviour of a connection ?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try 2 connections...

```
    conn1 = mysql.connector.connect(user=db['user'], password=db['password'], host=db['host'], port=db['port'], database="TEST", raise_on_warnings=True)
    conn2 = mysql.connector.connect(user=db['user'], password=db['password'], host=db['host'], port=db['port'], database="TEST", raise_on_warnings=True)
    cursor1 = conn1.cursor()
    self.send1Message(msg1) # Send to HTTP Webapp
    cursor1.execute(SELECT_TABLE1_BY_ID_AND_DATE, (idD, timing))
    print(cursor1.fetchall()) #1
    self.send2Message(msg2) Send to HTTP Webapp
    cursor2 = conn2.cursor()
    cursor2.execute(SELECT_TABLE2_BY_ID_AND_DATE, (idD, timing))
    print(cursor2.fetchall()) #2
```

Comment: I already tried with 2 connections.. I mentioned it in my post. I find the issue, I had to commit after the first fetchall.

Comment: My suggestion was to use 2 concurrent connections, did you try that? Good you have a solution anyway using commit after the fetchall.